# Error by conversion from Pyspark to Pandas

Tags: pandas, pyspark, valueerror

I am trying to convert a Pyspark dataframe to Pandas, so I simply write df1=df.toPandas(), and I get the error "ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1". Unfortunately, I don't see any other usefull information in the error message (it's quite long so i cannot post it here).
If somebody has an idea, what could be wrong, it would be nice.
I only saw this error in the case when a Pyspark dataframe had multiple columns with the same name, but this is not the case this time.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have experimented and found out, that the problem appears only if I select some specific columns. But I don't see what can be wrong with these columns.

Comment: would you mind posting some information about those columns? like sample data or how do you get `df1`?

Comment: I found the reason. It was the date column with the values "0001-01-01". I would say, it's really idiotic that Pandas cannot accept these values. :(