# Pyspark convertion toPandas() problem, ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

Hello every everyone !

I am reading data from DataLake (that holds a database tables) using PySpark and of applying some filters I put them in Spark DataFrame, but when I convert it to Pandas Data frame using toPandas(), I get this error: ErrorValue: ordinal must be >= 1 on jupyter.

```
all_columns = list(df.columns)
df = spark_df.select(all_columns)
new_df = df.toPandas()
```

*ValueError:  ordinal must be >= 1*

Is there anyone has an idea how to fix this bug please !

Thank you in advance !

I tried sparkDataFrame.toPandas()

I expected to get a pandas DataFrame

Comment: a sample of your dataframe would be helpful. could you include the output from `df.show(5)` in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68604602/error-by-conversion-from-pyspark-to-pandas) StackOverflow question. Double-check if there are strange date values in your PySpark Dataframe before transforming to pandas. You can check out the MIN and MAX dates for pandas dataframes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310740/what-is-the-oldest-time-that-can-be-represented-in-python).